# VS Code para python requiere el paquete ipykernel

Tags: python, vscode, jupyter

estoy intentando utilizar por primera vez un jupyter notebook en Visual Studio Code, pero me da siempre este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
La ejecución de celdas con 'Python 3.9.13 64-bit (windows store)' requieren el paquete ipykernel.
Ejecute el siguiente comando para instalar 'ipykernel' en el entorno de Python. comando 
: '"c:/Users/Juan Martin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe" -m pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall' '''
```

Comment: El mensaje te dice la solución. ¿Cual es la duda?

Comment: Que no funciona tampoco la solución.

Comment: instalastes python para un solo usuaria los recomendable es desintalarlo y instalarlo para todos los usuarios...

Comment: Gracias esa fue la solución!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tambien puedes instalarlo en tu entorno virtual con:

```
pip install ipykernel
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema era efectivamente que instale python para un solo usuario, cuando lo recomendable es desintalarlo y instalarlo para todos los usuarios!!